# AWS EC2 - Get access logs of AWS EC2 Instance logged in by RDP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rdp

I have created a windows instance and got .rdp file. How can i get the access logs i.e WHO and WHEN the instance is logged into with this .rdp file. Also, how much time was it used. Need help with the approaches of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

- You can **RDP** to the instance and *configure it* just like any other Windows server.
- Then in AWS in the **Instance Security Group** open the necessary network ports.
- Use something like **[Windows Remote Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winrm/portal)** to retrieve your logs and other stats.

Hope that helps :)